# I cant show my mysql results in my html page

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have been trying to show my mysql results i get with php to show on my html site.
But they just dont show up. I am making this for my final assigment and i would really like some help.

The desired effect of this code is : Get a choice of a list and submit that. The user then gets the results back. 
But this code does not even send the choice. The choice list does not even open.

Here you can see my code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC >
<html >
<head>
<title>Informatica opdracht</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="English" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrap">
<h1><a href="#">Onze Game shop </a></h1>
<div id="header">

</div>

<div id="content">
<div class="right"> 

<h2><a href="#">Hoe het eruit ziet.</a></h2>
<div class="articles">

<br /><br />
<img src="images/game.jpg" width="200" height= "200" alt="game shop" style="border: 3px solid #ccc;" />
<br /><br />
Welkom op onze online gameshop. Via het menu links kun je een spel of een reservering bekijken.
</div>
<h2><a href="#">Kies hier je spel</a></h2>
<div class="articles">
Kies via dit menu je gewenste spel: 

<?php 
$mysql = mysql_connect("localhost","root","usbw") or die("Fout: Er is geen verbinding met de MySQL-server tot stand gebracht!");
mysql_select_db("games",$mysql) or die("Fout: Het openen van de database is mislukt!");
$resultaat = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT categorie FROM games",$mysql) or die("De query op de database is mislukt!");
mysql_close($mysql) or die("Het verbreken van de verbinding met de MySQL-server is mislukt!");
?>
<form action="test.php" method="post">
Kies een categorie:<br />
<select name="categorie">

<?php
while(list($categorie) = mysql_fetch_row($resultaat))
{
print("<option value='$categorie'>$categorie</option>");
}
?> 
</select><br />
<input type="submit" value="Verzend" />
</form>



</div>
</div>

<div class="left"> 

<h2>Kies hier :</h2>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Games</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Reserveringen</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Log in </a></li> 

</ul>


</div>
<div style="clear: both;"> </div>
</div>

    <div id="bottom"> </div>
    <div id="footer">

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

That is my html site

Comment: Is the file extension `.php` ?

Comment: So what _exactly_ do you mean by "But they just dont show up"? Do you get your html page? Or a blank page? Is the page content broken somehow? Tell us! What do you see in your http servers error log file? What do you learn if you use your browsers development console to examine the DOM tree of elements actually loaded?

Comment: What errors do you get? Also there is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are 
[**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** 
and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the 
future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or 
[MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: @j08691 Your comment is outdated. The future is now. The `MySQL_*` functions have been removed.

Comment: @GolezTrol - Feel free to update http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136609/repository-of-useful-pro-forma-comments

Comment: Didn't know about that. But ok, done.

Comment: Hello everybody thanks for your answers. The problem with this code is that when i want to choose the categories on my html page the results dont come up. i cant even choose the categories from the choice list

Comment: I have made a screenshot of the problem that i see on the html site. http://snag.gy/KeEfE.jpg. Maybe this will be able to help you guys a little more @arkascha

Comment: @j08691  Here you can see more information

Comment: The php is not parsed, is this a php file and are you opening it from a web-server?

Comment: @jeroen. Hello jeroen. This is my html file and its running from usb webserver. Would you need my php file aswell?

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while since I have used `mysql_*` but it looks like you are closing the connection too soon; you have not even retrieved your rows yet when you do:

```
...
$resultaat = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT categorie FROM games",$mysql) or die("De query op de database is mislukt!");
mysql_close($mysql) or die("Het verbreken van de verbinding met de MySQL-server is mislukt!");
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ This does not look good
?>
...
```

You should remove the `mysql_close()` line.

And you should probably move to PDO or mysqli while you are at it as the `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated in php 5.5+ and they have been removed completely from php 7.

Comment: Hey jeroen. Thanks alot for your answer. I would normally always choose to use the latest functions but my teacher requires us to use mysql. I will try to remove this line and report back.!

Comment: Hey @jeroen. I removed that line and it still does not work, You can see the enclosed screenshot of the problem. De keuzelijst komt niet tevoorschijn.          http://snag.gy/KeEfE.jpg